# Multiply a single number to a multidimensional array in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to multiply a number that i choose to a multidimensional array with values that i have chose, but my code doesn't do that.

Here it is the multiplication function:

```
int product_array(){
i = 0;
j = 0;
int number;
int product[i][j];
printf("Insert the number\n");
scanf("%d", &number);
while (i < rows) {
    printf("\n");
    j = 0;
    while (j < columns) {
        product[i][j] = number + product[0][0] * m_array[i][j];
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
i = 0;
j = 0;
printf("Here it is the product\n");
while (i < rows) {
    printf("\n");
    j = 0;
    while (j < columns) {
        printf("\t%d ", product[i][j]);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    printf("\n");
}
return product[i][j];
}
```

Legend: `m_array` means `multidimensional array`

Example of input ad output

Input

- m_array values = 2 2 2 2
- Number = 2

Output

- 4 4 4 4

To be clearer this is the piece of code with which the user can insert the values into the `m_array`:

```
do {
    printf("How many rows will be in the array?\n");
    scanf("%d", &righe);
} while (rows > Row || rows < 1);

do {
    printf("How many columns will be in the array?\n");
    scanf("%d", &columns);
} while (columns > Column || columns < 1);

printf("Data input\n");
while (i < rows) {
    j=0;
    while (j < columns) {
        printf("Insert the element in the %d column and %d row\n", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &m_array[i][j]);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This declaration int product[i][j]; is invalid when i and j are equal to 0.

Comment: Also this statement product[i][j] = number + product[0][0] * m_array[i][j]; does not make a sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ok, so what i have to do? The first thing that came up in my mind was to assign to `product[0][0]` the `number` value but i don't know how to do it

Comment: You already wrote what you need to do "Multiply a single number to a multidimensional array" So there is no need to declare one more array.

Comment: Oh, now i see, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out what the problem was (pretty simple), here is the code with the solution:

```
int product_array(){
i = 0;
j = 0;
int number;
printf("Insert the number\n");
scanf("%d", &number);
while (i < rows) {
printf("\n");
j = 0;
while (j < columns) {
    m_array[i][j] = number * m_array[i][j];
    j++;
}
i++;
}
i = 0;
j = 0;
printf("Here it is the product\n");
while (i < rows) {
printf("\n");
j = 0;
while (j < columns) {
    printf("\t%d ", m_array[i][j]);
    j++;
}
i++;
printf("\n");
}
return m_array[i][j];
}
```